# How can I de-obfuscate not only the stack trace but also the whole log file?

Tags: java, proguard, obfuscation, deobfuscation

It seems an easy task: run retrace on the log and get the names of my classes and methods. but retrace only does part of the job and deobfuscate just the stack trace and not all the other log records. I have an ordinary log line:

```
07/11/16 11:17:26 Info thread:GeneralFactory : at com.a.b.c.d(SourceFile:482)-Some Text
```

I want **com.a.b.c.d(SourceFile:482)** to also be deobfuscated. I reviewed the ProGuard manual and tried to use the `-regex` with the provided example but failed. I would appreciate any regex help or any other idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't explain why the retrace.jar doesn't de-obfuscate the entire log - just the stack trace. Maybe it has to do with the pattern format of each log record.
Anyhow I used the `-regex` which is quite easy once you get a hold on it, however using '%' in this RE and sending it as a variable in a batch file made my life hell for several hours.
I'm enclosing my final batch file - hope it will help someone in the future:

```
@echo off
@setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set RE=!(?:.*?\sat\s%%%%c\.%%%%m\s*\(%%%%s(?::%%%%l)?\)(?:.*)?)!

REM use ! to avoid turning %...% to a variable
REM use %%%% so it becomes %% before it is sent to the retrace.jar
REM add (?: to the variable because it is cut - don't know why...

set RE_FINAL=(?:%RE%
call java -jar proguard5.2.1/retrace.jar -regex %RE_FINAL% obfu-mapping.txt "%1"
```

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the below points.

1. open the terminal/cmd
2. cd **/sdk/tools/proguard/bin/proguardgui.jar
3. refer the attached image, retrace GUI pop's up
4. select your mapping file and copy-paste your obfuscated stacktrace or hole Log

That's it. Simple and easy

[image]

Comment: https://jar-download.com/artifacts/net.sf.proguard/proguard-gui/5.0/source-code here the link